# Do we need to consider "direction" while discussing regions of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Consider the following double integral from Thomas' Calculus
$$\int_0^3 \int_1^{4-2u} \frac{4-2u}{v^2} \ dv\ du;$$

sketch the region of integration.

If we represent $u$ on the horizontal axis and $v$ on the vertical axis and sketch the limits, we get

[image]

For $0 \leq u \leq \frac{3}{2}$, we have $1 \leq 4-2u$ (blue region); for $\frac{3}{2} \leq u \leq 3$, we have $1 \geq 4-2u$ (orange region).

Is this sketch correct?

Do we have to consider the direction when discussing the region of integration?

I think this is a higher dimensional parallel to the convention that
$$\int_a^b f\left( x \right) \ dx = -\int_b^a f\left( x \right) \ dx$$

Can someone point me to a reference with more details on this?

If you find the presentation of my question confusing, I am very sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very clear.

This problem from the book is not well-formulated and it causes confusion.

My suggestion to you is just forget about the problem.

If you really want to work on the problem, then I have to say that the region of integration is ``directed'' and you are right on this.

Sorry for using comment as an answer. I am new here and still can not make a comment.